# How to center LegendLabel in BarLegend

Tags: legending

`BarLegend` leaves a white region at the other end of the legend (the "0 end"), which is best seen by plotting a frame around the legend:

```
BarLegend["Rainbow", LegendFunction -> "Frame"]
BarLegend["Rainbow", LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

[image]

This behaviour causes that the `LegendLabel` is not centered with respect to the color bar (in the following plots, the label is not at the 0.5 tick). It appears that the label is centered with respect to the whole legend, which includes the white region, even when the frame is not plotted:

```
BarLegend["Rainbow", LegendLabel -> Placed["1", Right]]
BarLegend["Rainbow", LegendLabel -> Placed["1", Right], LegendFunction -> "Frame"]
BarLegend["Rainbow", LegendLabel -> "1", LegendLayout -> "Row"]
BarLegend["Rainbow", LegendLabel -> "1", LegendLayout -> "Row", LegendFunction -> "Frame"]
```

[image]

How can I place the `LegendLabel` so that it appears centered with respect to the color bar (both in horizontal and vertical `BarLegend`s)?

When the option `LegendLayout->"Row"` is used, a possibility is to leave some white space before the label, but this is far from ideal:

```
BarLegend["Rainbow", LegendLabel -> "   1", LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For version 9, the culprit seems to be the `ImagePadding` settings:

```
bl1 = BarLegend[{"LakeColors", {0, 1}}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8}, 
                LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendLabel -> Placed["1", Right]];
bl2 = BarLegend[{"LakeColors", {0, 1}}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8}, 
              LegendFunction -> "Frame", LegendLayout -> "Row", LegendLabel -> Placed["1", Top]];

Cases[ToBoxes[#], HoldPattern[ImagePadding -> _], {0, Infinity}] & /@ {bl1, bl2}
(* {{ImagePadding -> {{1, All}, {All, All}}},{ImagePadding -> {{All, All}, {All, 1}}}} *)
```

A work-around is to post-process the `BarLegend` output to change the `ImagePadding` values using a function like

```
correctPaddingF =  RawBoxes[ToBoxes[#] /. HoldPattern[ImagePadding -> p_] :>
      (ImagePadding -> (If[ p == {{1, All}, {All, All}}, {{1, All}, {1, All}}, 
                          {{1, All}, {All, 1}}]))] &; 

Row[{bl1, correctPaddingF@bl1}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

```
Row[{bl2, correctPaddingF@bl2}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

```
bl3 = BarLegend[{"LakeColors", {0, 1}}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8}, 
                LegendLabel -> Placed["1", Right]];
bl4 = BarLegend[{"LakeColors", {0, 1}}, {0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.8}, 
                LegendLayout -> "Row", LegendLabel -> Placed["1", Top]];

Row[{bl3, correctPaddingF@bl3}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

```
Row[{bl4, correctPaddingF@bl4}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
BarLegend["Rainbow", LegendMargins -> {{25, 10}, {0, 15}}, 
 LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0, 
     RoundingRadius -> 10] &)]
```

[image]

For label placement you can use

```
BarLegend["Rainbow", LegendMargins -> {{25, 10}, {0, 15}}, 
 LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, FrameMargins -> 0, 
     RoundingRadius -> 10] &), 
 LegendLabel -> Placed[Column[{"1", ""}, Spacings -> 0], Right]]
```

[image]

For horizontal label  you can use `LegendLabel -> Placed[Row[{"    ", "1"}], Bottom]`

Comment: Thanks. This solution provides a way to make a centered frame. However, this doesn’t affect the label placement.