# How can I rotate the LegendLabel in MatrixPlot and extract the color scheme to be used in DensityPlot?

Tags: plotting, color, legending

```
    data = Table[
   Sin[x] Cos[y] + 0.05 x y, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
MatrixPlot[data, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 100, 
    LegendLabel -> 
     Placed[Style[Text["(Text for Label)"], Red, FontSize -> 22], 
      Top]], Right], AspectRatio -> 2]
```

I really have to questions:

**updated**

1. how can I rotate (90 `Degree`, see fig below) the red `LegendLabel` to be aligned with `BarLegend`?
2. I want to extract the color scheme in the `MatrixPlot` so I can use it in `DensityPlot`.

[image]

Comment: What about putting the legend bar horizontally above the matrix plot, and putting the label horizontally above the bar. To my opinion, it makes more sense esthetically.

Comment: @yarchik, you are right but I have four panels and I want to stack them together and above, and below the plot, I have different labels.

Comment: Maybe this is relevant? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69952/how-to-center-legendlabel-in-barlegend

Comment: As to 2nd question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104039/1871

Comment: Just replace Right by Top in my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = Table[
   Sin[x] Cos[y] + 0.05 x y, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}, {y, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}];
MatrixPlot[data, AspectRatio -> 2, DataReversed -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> {25, 250}, 
   LegendLabel -> 
    Placed[Style["(Text for Label)", 22, Red], Top, 
     Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &]]]
```

[image]

---

You can use [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/161647/how-to-mimic-matlab-parula-color-scheme-efficiently/161683#161683) approach.

[image]

Double click legend and copy and paste.

```
im=(*put image of legend here*)


 matrixPlotColor = Module[{colorlist}, colorlist = Join @@ ImageData@im;
   Evaluate[Blend[RGBColor @@@ Reverse[colorlist], #] &]];

DensityPlot[Sin[x] Cos[y] + 0.05 x y, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {y, 0, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> All, ColorFunction -> matrixPlotColor, ImageSize -> 220,
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 2, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer!

Comment: in the last fig. with DensityPlot, why the white color is not at zer in the BarLegend?

Comment: See my edit. We need to reverse color. It works now.